# Better ways (more git like) to version release pipelines in Azure DevOps?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

The approach we are currently using in Azure Devops for releases when a pipeline change is required.

- Clone active release and increment the version number
- Reenter all the secrets, and make amendments to new pipeline.
- When validated, promote cloned pipeline to current pipeline (via rename)
- Flag old pipeline as Old and keep around (because if we delete it we loose release history)

Why do we do this?

- Do not want to interrupt the current active pipeline with WIP.
- VSTS doesn't seem to allow git like versioning/branching of release pipelines.

Question,  does anyone have a better way of doing versioned pipeline work more aligned to a git like model.  Ideally we'd love to

- Branch the current pipeline, (keeping secrets)
- Do work on branch pipeline.
- When validated, merge new pipeline back into current pipeline.
  [image]

Comment: You might want to watch this feature ([Configuration as code (YAML) releases - Public Preview](https://dev.azure.com/mseng/Azure%20DevOps%20Roadmap/_workitems/edit/1221170)) as it might be a requirement to simplify what you are wanting to achieve.

Comment: nothing to take a look at, right? its not out yet, even in preview

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this question has no utility anymore, as YAML pipelines accomplish exactly this and are the standard way of creating pipelines.

Answer (score 1):

none of the ci\cd tools I've worked with allow anything like what you are proposing so no, that is not possible. but what you could do - you could create new environments inside existing release job (say dev-new, next to dev) and configure task steps. advantages: you keep variables, you can clone existing tasks and amend them, applying changes is as simple as deleting old environments